# how to implement password reset in Django without using Django auth and forms

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am new to python and i want to implement reset password using emails.

is it possible to make it without using Django `auth` and Django `forms`?

Comment: What do you mean without using Django `auth`? If you're not using Django's built in authentication in some way, you may be better off using Flask or another python framework. Django is only one option.

Comment: @schillingt i am new to django and i have never used django `auth` so i don't know how to work with django authentication. how am i supposed to use django `auth` without `User` model? is it possible to do so? if yes, how? i have my own model instead of `User` model.

Comment: There is documentation to help you with that. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Comment: yes I have read the docs. but it's not much helpful for me.@schillingt can you provide some another guide? thankyou